# How to test parent call method in a class for phpspec

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpspec

I have a class with parent call method in it. I want to make sure that parent have been called so that when I edit tested method and remove that line it will fail tests

My class:

```
public function myMethod($object)
{
    parent::myMethod($object);
    ..
}
```

My test (spec):

```
/*
 * @param \Example\Entity\MyEntity $myEntity
 */
function it_cat_call_my_method_example($myEntity)
{
    $this->myMethod($myEntity)->shouldParentHaveBeenCalled(); // what to do here?
}
```

Is that possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible in the way you describe.

What would the benefit of testing a call to parent be? You presumably want to test whether some behaviour the parent implements happens, so call that directly.

Put another way, if I rewrite my class to not call parent and instead implement the same functionality, I don't think the test should fail.

Answer (score 3):

I don't believe it's possible. PHPSpec lets you test your public API (and calls to collaborators) but not anything to do with inheritance.

Comment: You can assert against type, which is directly relevant to inheritance.

There isn't much else you *should* test, because inheritance doesn't really effect your class's external behaviour.